# how to retrieve data in multiple selected list

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, cakephp-2.0

i need to retrive data in mutiple selected list from database

in my database value is

Marathi,Arunachali,Assamese,Awadhi,Marathi,Arunachali,Assamese,Awadhi

i used the below code to retrive

```
     <select id="spokenlanguages" name="known_languages[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
                 <option value="" >Select</option>
                  <?php 
                    $langs =  $editdatapersonaltbl[0]['known_languages'] ;                  

                    $known_languages = explode(",",$langs); 

                    //print_r($known_languages); exit();

                    for($i=0;$i < count($known_languages);$i++)
                    {  
                   ?>               
                  <option value="<?php echo $known_languages[$i] ;?>"  selected="selected"><?php echo $known_languages[$i] ;?></option>                     
                  <?php } ?>  

                  <option value="Marathi" >Marathi</option>
                  <option value="Arunachali" >Arunachali</option>
                  <option value="Assamese" >Assamese</option>
                  <option value="Awadhi" >Awadhi</option>
                  <option value="Bengali" >Bengali</option>
                  <option value="Bhojpuri" >Bhojpuri</option>
                  <option value="Brij" >Brij</option>
                  <option value="Bihari" >Bihari</option>
</select>
```

but my problem is if marathi is previously selected than it displayed in selected and 
not selected also

not selected because of  `<option value="Marathi" >Marathi</option>` option is there if i will remove this option `<option value="Marathi" >Marathi</option>` than if marathi is not in database than what if user want to select marathi

please provide me some solutions....

Comment: good! 3 frameworks in the tag....

Comment: what framework are you using clarify first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<select id="spokenlanguages" name="known_languages[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
         <option value="" >Select</option>
          <?php 
            $langs =  $editdatapersonaltbl[0]['known_languages'] ;                  

            $known_languages = explode(",",$langs);
            $known_languages    = array_filter( $known_languages ); #remove the blank values if any
            //print_r($known_languages); exit();
          ?>

          <option value="Marathi" <?php if(in_array('Marathi', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?> >Marathi</option>
          <option value="Arunachali" <?php if(in_array('Arunachali', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Arunachali</option>
          <option value="Assamese" <?php if(in_array('Assamese', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Assamese</option>
          <option value="Awadhi" <?php if(in_array('Awadhi', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Awadhi</option>
          <option value="Bengali" <?php if(in_array('Bengali', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Bengali</option>
          <option value="Bhojpuri" <?php if(in_array('Bhojpuri', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Bhojpuri</option>
          <option value="Brij" <?php if(in_array('Brij', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Brij</option>
          <option value="Bihari" <?php if(in_array('Bihari', $known_languages)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>Bihari</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wat if he have more than 100 lang in his select list? he need to write 'in_array' for each option..

Comment: Then he needs to store all the available languages in the database. How can I help here.? @Ashish

Comment: if im not wrong then he can store all lang. in array and use in_array only 1 time..

Comment: I have been looking to solve this problem days and days, I have done it because of your code above, Thanks Nil'z.

Comment: @MR.Internet Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

first u must put html options in array as html_aarray  , then cho database array . after that in another while eho html option if the node of html_aarray not exists in database array.

i wrote it 4 u , use this :http://codepad.org/gjWW9UGg

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

//$lang_array is ur language array
$lang_array = array('Marathi','Hindi','Gujrati','Bengali');

//this array ehich u fetching from DB
$known_languages = array('Marathi', 'Gujrati');
?>
 <select id="spokenlanguages" name="known_languages[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
 <option value="" >Select</option>

<?php

for($i=0;$i < count($lang_array); $i++)
{
    if(in_array($lang_array[$i], $known_languages))
    {
        $str = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        $str ='';
    }
echo 
'<option value="'.$lang_array[$i].'" '.$str.'> '.$lang_array[$i].'</option>';
}
?>
```